# Laravel multiple foreign keys get specific value using querybuilder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table of contracts and here is the example data

```
id     spec1        spec2          spec3
1        2            4              3
```

And i got another table of spec and the values are

```
id       text
1        hello
2        hi
3        hola
4        yow
```

how can i get the text from spec table? do i need to multiple join them?
what I want is something like

```
{
 contract.id: 1,
 spec1: hello,
 spec2: yow,
 spec3: hola,
}
{
 contract.id: 2,
 spec1: hello,
 spec2: yow,
 spec3: hola,
}
```

im selecting from contracts table

I tried

```
      DB::table('contracts as c')
            ->join('spec','spec.id','c.spec1')
            ->join('spec','spec.id','c.spec2')
            ->join('spec','spec.id','c.spec3')
            ->get();
```

but its wrong and got some errors. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi @Patas, can you plaese share the errors you came across? thanks

Comment: yes. actually i dont have errors. it returns an empty result @MarcelloPerri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:

```
 DB::table('contracts')->select('contracts.id','a.text AS spec1','b.text AS spec2','c.text AS spec3')
    ->leftJoin('specs AS a', 'a.id', 'contracts.spec1')
    ->leftJoin('specs AS b', 'b.id', 'contracts.spec2')
    ->leftJoin('specs AS c', 'c.id', 'contracts.spec3')
    ->get();
```

MySQL [documation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Read this [Question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/multiple-inner-joins-in-the-same-table)

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('contracts as c')
        ->leftjoin('spec as s1', 's1.id', '=', 'c.spec1')
        ->leftjoin('spec as s2', 's2.id', '=', 'c.spec2')
        ->leftjoin('spec as s3', 's3.id', '=', 'c.spec3')
        ->select('c.id as contract.id', 's1.text as spec1', 's2.text as spec2', 's3.text as spec3')
        ->get();
```

Let me know the results.

Comment: hello its correct and the same as the first one. thanks for this one :)